# A grave deception

Tags: riddle

> Here I lie, so famously 
>   Master of the edifice they named for me 
>   Eternal as a pyramid? You'd think, but no 
>   They'll both collapse, but mine takes even longer till it goes
>
> I was back then, as now, despised and hated 
>   Yet I continue to be reincarnated 
>   So long as men do dream of easy glory 
>   So long are men inspired to relive my story
>
> **Who am I?**

I will accept the first answer that answers the question correctly and explains all the clues (make sure you look carefully, some of them are not obvious even when you know the answer).

This is my third riddle, so I'll also welcome any feedback or critique that helps me improve (in the comments, or in the form of an answer if it needs to contain spoilers). If you liked this riddle, here are my previous two: [1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/24847/17947), [2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/24941/17947).

**Edit -- A Hint:**

> Look deeper to find the scheme of the riddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> Charles Ponzi?

`Here I lie, so famously 
Master of the edifice they named for me`

> The 'Ponzi Scheme' (as hinted at in your...hint) was named for him  **EDIT:** lol, I just got the pun—intended or otherwise—in "here I *lie*"

`Eternal as a pyramid? You'd think, but no 
They'll both collapse, but mine takes even longer till it goes`

> A reference to a 'pyramid scheme' - a similar (but different!) type of money-making scheme. From [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponzi_scheme#Similar_schemes): *"A pyramid scheme typically collapses much faster because it requires exponential increases in participants to sustain it. By contrast, Ponzi schemes can survive simply by persuading most existing participants to reinvest their money, with a relatively small number of new participants"*

`I was back then, as now, despised and hated 
Yet I continue to be reincarnated`

> Charles Ponzi was a notorious con artist, deceiving many in his life

`So long as men do dream of easy glory 
So long are men inspired to relive my story`

> A Ponzi Scheme, cleverly executed, would be a source of easy money for those who would endeavor the risk

Comment: Nice! Yes, the pun was intended, as is hinted at by the title of the riddle, which contains another double entendre. Also, "reincarnated" refers to (spoiler:) [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ponzi_schemes).

Comment: I figured that was what you were going for there, wasn't sure if that was covered in the last two lines already, though.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are

> Ozymandias

Here I lie, so famously

> Many people know Shelley's poem Ozymandias

Master of the edifice they named for me

> The poem is named for the man (it is the Greek name for Rameses II)

Eternal as a pyramid? You'd think, but no/They'll both collapse, but mine takes even longer till it goes

> The poem will eventually be forgotten, but it's currently around even after pyramids have fallen

I was back then, as now, despised and hated

> Both when the poem was written, and now, people make fun of Ozymandias

Yet I continue to be reincarnated/So long as men do dream of easy glory/So long are men inspired to relive my story

> As long as foolish people say things about their works living forever, others will mock them by bringing up the poem

Comment: Whoa, I never would've thought of that!

Comment: Another very nice solution, +1, though I personally wasn't very familiar with the poem, so it's still quite far from the correct answer. However I like that you made use of some important clues, even if not exactly in the way I intended... Anyway, I added a hint, maybe that will guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Jesus Christ?

Here I lie, so famously

Master of the edifice they named for me

> An edifice is both a building and a complex set of beliefs. Jesus died at the cross, but the cross is also a symbol of the Christian belief (named after Christ).

Eternal as a pyramid? You'd think, but no

They'll both collapse, but mine takes even longer till it goes

> This is referring to the eventual collapse of religion, though the longstanding belief in Christianity mandates that it'll be around as long as people 'need' it, as beliefs often last longer than objects themselves.

I was back then, as now, despised and hated

Yet I continue to be reincarnated

> The Bible describes Jesus as a figure who was killed out of hatred for his beliefs, yet we continue to believe that he will come again. We celebrate holidays such as Easter Sunday to represent his reincarnation.

So long as men do dream of easy glory

So long are men inspired to relive my story

> People often use religion as a way to justify themselves. They believe that repentance and belief will send them to a heaven of eternal joy. This belief is what impels people to preach the word of the Bible. They rely on this idea of eternal glory past the end of their lives.

Comment: +1 for a very nice answer+solution... that are **COMPLETELY** different from what I had in mind. :-)